# Number counter increases the number from 1 to the heighest value and then decreases it from that value to 1. But it should increases and then stop

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Hey everyone!** I tried to make `number-counter` when i will see it, everything  great until the moment when i saw that the number raised from `1` to `85` and then from `85` to `1`  (It should increases and then stop). I tried to fix that by adding the feature which launches counter function **only once**, but that did't work out.

If you have offers, i beg you to share with me please)

```js
// Persent-counter
var isResizeble_1 = false;
var isResizeble_2 = false;

function first_num_count(){
 if(!isResizeble_2) {
    // The count function
  $('#count-num').each(function(){
   $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
    Counter: $(this).text()
   },{
    duration: 2000,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function(now){
     $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
    }
   });
  });

  isRezeble_2 = true;
 }
}

// The trigger element
var firstPersent = document.querySelector('#persent');

var Visible = function (target) {
  // Get elem's positions
  var targetPosition = {
   top: window.pageYOffset + target.getBoundingClientRect().top,
   left: window.pageXOffset + target.getBoundingClientRect().left,
   right: window.pageXOffset + target.getBoundingClientRect().right,
   bottom: window.pageYOffset + target.getBoundingClientRect().bottom
  },
    // Get window's positions
    windowPosition = {
     top: window.pageYOffset,
     left: window.pageXOffset,
     right: window.pageXOffset + document.documentElement.clientWidth,
     bottom: window.pageYOffset + document.documentElement.clientHeight
    };

    if (targetPosition.bottom > windowPosition.top &&
     targetPosition.top < windowPosition.bottom &&
     targetPosition.right > windowPosition.left &&
     targetPosition.left < windowPosition.right) {
     
    // If we see the elem
 // Do our counting function only once
 if(!isResizeble_1) {
  first_num_count();
  isRezeble_1 = true;
 }

  }
};

// Start function onscroll
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
 Visible(firstPersent);
});
```

```css
body{
  height 900px;
}

.number-persent{
  margin-top: 600px;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="number-persent">
    <p id="count-num">85</p>
    <p id="persent">%</p>
  </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: Make sure your variables are spelled correctly, or at least consistent: `isRezeble_1`

Comment: I've rechecked my vars, everything should be ok with it. but to be 200% sure, i replaced `isRezeble_1` and `isRezeble_2` to another vars

Comment: move `var isResizeble_2 = false;` outside the function otherwise it will always run what's in the `if`

Comment: __James__, okay, i moved `isResizeble_1` and `isResizeble_2` outside, but unfortunately that is not working?

Comment: May it be because of my empty `else`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move var isResizeble_2 = false; outside the function otherwise it will always run what's in the if.  And fix your variable name typos.

```js
   var isResizeble_2 = false;
// Persent-counter
function first_num_count(){

 if(!isResizeble_2) {
    // The count function
  $('#count-num').each(function(){
   $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
    Counter: $(this).text()
   },{
    duration: 2000,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function(now){
     $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
    }
   });
  });

  isResizeble_2 = true;
 }
}

// The trigger element
var firstPersent = document.querySelector('#persent');

var Visible = function (target) {
  // Get elem's positions
  var targetPosition = {
   top: window.pageYOffset + target.getBoundingClientRect().top,
   left: window.pageXOffset + target.getBoundingClientRect().left,
   right: window.pageXOffset + target.getBoundingClientRect().right,
   bottom: window.pageYOffset + target.getBoundingClientRect().bottom
  },
    // Get window's positions
    windowPosition = {
     top: window.pageYOffset,
     left: window.pageXOffset,
     right: window.pageXOffset + document.documentElement.clientWidth,
     bottom: window.pageYOffset + document.documentElement.clientHeight
    };

    if (targetPosition.bottom > windowPosition.top &&
     targetPosition.top < windowPosition.bottom &&
     targetPosition.right > windowPosition.left &&
     targetPosition.left < windowPosition.right) {
     
    // If we see the elem
 // Do our counting function only once
 var isResizeble_1 = false;

 if(!isResizeble_1) {
  first_num_count();
  isResizeble_1 = true;
 }

} else {
    // If we don't see the elem
    
};
};

// Start function onscroll
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
 Visible(firstPersent);
});
```

```css
body{
  height 900px;
}

.number-persent{
  margin-top: 600px;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="number-persent">
    <p id="count-num">85</p>
    <p id="persent">%</p>
  </div>
 </body>
```